# rails g migration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I don't know what to do. Try to use command

```
$ rails g migration vacancy
```

but this command give me error:

```
    invoke  active_record
/home/proger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 21 column 11 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /home/proger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse_stream'
    from /home/proger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'
    ...
```

There are many rows in error code

I don't know how to fix that  Thanks

**UPDATE**

> development:
>   adapter: mysql2
>   encoding: utf8
>   reconnect: false
>   database: jobs
>   pool: 5
>   username: root
>   password: toor
>   socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

**update:** 
with sqlite3 there is no problem. problem in mysql gem

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you have syntax error in yaml file. Probably it is in `config/database.yml`

Comment: All settings for each environment must be indented to follow yaml syntax. Just indent every line except `development:` with 2 spaces. Hope it will help.

Comment: May be. But anyway the problem is in one (or more) yaml file in your project if exception is raised by Psych gem.