# How do I address the Yaml error that rake keeps giving me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake, capistrano

I am close to throwing my laptop out the window here. I have been googling for a couple of hours and it seems I have been trying everything to remove this warning as I believe it is causing me problems. Here is my problem:

I am using `cap deploy` on my local machine and as soon as it gets to `rake assets:precompile`  I get a warning about `Yaml` saying

> It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output)

followed by some errors which I feel shouldn't be showing up. The errors show up in files that were generated when I made my project, which is really confusing me and also makes me feel like perhaps the Yaml warning could be a cause for these errors

```
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your 
ruby. rake aborted! can't convert String into Hash
/home3/dancheva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:253:in
`merge'
/home3/dancheva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:253:in
`root'
/home3/dancheva/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-3.2.14/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1328:in
`root'
```

I have tried removing the `~/.rvm/src/yaml*` folder and then used `rvm pkg install libyaml`. After which I reinstalled the rvm ruby using:

> rvm reinstall 1.9.3

and then later I tried

> rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-libyaml-dir=~/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4/

Can anyone help me? The warning won't go away and I don't know what I am doing wrong. This is getting so frustrating :(

---

Update:
I tried running `rake assets:precompile` on the local project. I didn't get the Yaml erro but I am still getting syntax errors in generated files it seems. Is it possible this has something to do with the ruby version I am using? I know that there was a syntax change between 1.8 and 1.9. That is the reason I switched to 1.9 though, because I was getting syntax errors that seemed to have sprung from building the project in a different version of ruby.
The errors from the local machine are as follows:

```
[TopGun-Air danchevalierca]$ rake assets:precompile
/Users/danchevalier/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby
/Users/danchevalier/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/rake
assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets rake
aborted! (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context
at line 7 column 12
/Users/danchevalier/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in
`database_configuration'
/Users/danchevalier/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:84:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
...
```

I'm not sure if this provides any insight into what might be going on but I am very new to all of this and very confused/flustered

Comment: Does `rake assets:precompile` work if you run it directly?

Comment: @carolclarinet I made sure to try it on the server on its own and it produces the same thing

Comment: Long shot but try deleting Gemfile.lock and running `bundle install` or running `bundle update`

Comment: Does running rake assets:precompile work when you run it locally? That at least would tell us if it's something in your server's environment if it works locally. If it doesn't work, then it's either a problem with your application's code or the same problem with your server and local environments :-/

Comment: I just tried running it on my local machine. I edited the question with an update to say what I found. I have a feeling it won't be helpful. Hopefully it provides some insight

Comment: That does help :) I think it's a formatting issue with one of your Yaml files. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337975/rails-g-migration-error) and [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoid/GfQF6iGN8UM) got that error message. The 2nd post recommends using this [online yaml parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) to help debug. If that doesn't expose the issue, can you paste your `config/database.yml` without any passwords or sensitive information but maintaining newlines and spaces?

Comment: Also, were you running this project with 1.8 before? Ruby's yaml implementation changed from Syck to Psych between 1.8 and 1.9, so that might explain it if your yaml files were generated by 1.8 and are trying to be read by 1.9.

Comment: I think it was 1.8 but since I was getting parse errors I thought that maybe I had accidentally generated it in 1.9 which is why I tried reconfiguring my system using rvm... It has been one big mess. I actually ended up redoing it today making sure to keep everything consistent between local and server. It has been much more successful so far :D The only downside is I have to transfer over all of my code :\